# Horizontally striped colors on ultra wide monitor

Tags: display, intel-graphics, colors

I run Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a Lenovo T550 with an Intel 5500 graphics chip.

I got a new [Philips 345E2AE](https://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/345E2AE_00/ultrawide-lcd-monitor) ultra wide monitor, that is connected via [this cable](https://silklandtech.com/products/4k-mini-displayport-to-displayport-cable).

My problem is that some colors look like they have 1px high horizontal stripes in them; as if the monitor or graphics card does not output 24bit color and needs to interpolate some. Especially orange, blue and pink colors show this striped-color phenomenon.

I tried to capture [this color gradient](https://nikonites.com/attachments/photography-q-and-a/677d1394854901-color-space-srgb-adobe-rgb-100-percent-ramp.jpg) with my phone, but the phenomenon is hardly visible on the picture...I marked the relevant colors with red arrows.

[image]

Any idea on how to get smooth looking colors?

---

Update:
I got access to a MacBook Air (Intel 6000 graphics chip) and it shows the same weird behavior. It even shows an additional glitch. Here you see a photo that I took while the monitor was connected to a the MacBook Air. You can see the Ubuntu logo from the Settings > About page (like burned in) in it!? So is this a problem with the Intel graphic chips and this specific monitor?

[image]

Comment: I have what might be the same problem. Thin horizontal stripes appear periodically. I upgraded to 22.04 LTS a few weeks ago, but this problem started only yesterday. I wish I know whether this is due to the graphics card, the display settings, a cable, or the display itself.